# Html code inside Php statement if User is admin

Tags: php, html, session, admin

I'm stuck. I want to show different menu options, wether the user is normal user, semi-admin or main-admin. In my authentication when the user log in, I set up a $_SESSION['login'] followed by a number, which I want to use later on which I will show.

```
if ($num_rows > 0) {
            if ($username == "KP") {
                session_start();
                $_SESSION['login'] = '4';
                header("Location: Index.php");
            } else if($username == "FH"){
                session_start();
                $_SESSION['login'] = '3';
                header("Location: Index.php");
            } else{
                session_start();
                $_SESSION['login'] = '1';
                header("Location: Index.php");
            }
        } else {
            $errorMessage = "Error";
            return $errorMessage;
        }
```

So based on the username which is used to log in, it gives a special session number, right?
1 is normal member, 3 is the co-admin member, and 4 is the main-admin.

In my Menu, when the user is logged in, I want to show special features for the admins.

```
<?php elseif (isset($_SESSION['login'])) : ?>

    <li class="separator"></li>
    <li><a href="#Web-Menus" class="arrow">Profile / Logout</a>

        <div class="drop decor3_2 dropToLeft" style="width: 460px; height: 240px;">
            <div class='left'>
                <b>Profile</b>
                <div>
                    <a href="#">Profile</a><br/>
                    <a href="#">#</a><br/>
                    <a href="#">#</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class='left'>
                <br/>

                <div>
                    <a href="Logout.php">Logout</a><br/>
                </div>
            </div>

            <?php if($_SESSION['login'] == 4) : ?>
                <div class="left">
                    <div>
                        <a href="#">Session4 KP</a><br/>
                        <a href="#">Session4 KP</a><br/>
                        <a href="#">Session4 KP</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if($_SESSION['login'] == 3) : ?>
                <div class="left">
                    <div>
                        <a href="#">Session3 FH</a><br/>
                        <a href="#">Session3 FH</a><br/>
                        <a href="#">Session3 FH</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    </li>

<?php endif; ?>
```

So as you can see, for the user KabelPlus with the session number 4, there should be some extra stuff to do in the menu, but stuff that wont appear if $_SESSION['login'] != 3 or 4.

My problem is, the ekstra Links in the menu doesn't appear even tho im logged in as KP or FH. What's wrong with this?

Comment: return the `$_SESSION['login']` to see if it's returning your desired number. Or you can check through your browser.

Comment: Maybe the problem is with your `elseif` in your view `<?php elseif (isset($_SESSION['login'])) : ?>` Check if this is your problem, and like user3278616 said print your login number on screen.

Comment: before this elseif statement, I have a statement that says, if there are no session['login'], the two opportunities in the menu are CreateUser/Login. That works :) I do have session_start() on this page too, and all the other pages :)

Answer (score 1):

You should include the html inside the php code:

```
         <?php if(isset($_SESSION['login'])) {

             print("<li class='separator'></li>
             <li><a href='#Web-Menus' class='arrow'>Profile / Logout</a>

    <div class='drop decor3_2 dropToLeft' style='width: 460px; height: 240px;'>
        <div class='left'>
            <b>Profile</b>
            <div>
                <a href='#'>Profile</a><br/>
                <a href='#'>#</a><br/>
                <a href='#'>#</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='left'>
            <br/>

            <div>
                <a href='Logout.php'>Logout</a><br/>
            </div>
        </div>");

         if($_SESSION['login'] == 4) {
            print("<div class='left'>
                <div>
                    <a href='#'>Session4 KP</a><br/>
                    <a href='#'>Session4 KP</a><br/>
                    <a href='#'>Session4 KP</a>
                </div>
            </div>");} elseif($_SESSION['login'] == 3) {

            print("<div class='left'>
                <div>
                    <a href='#'>Session3 FH</a><br/>
                    <a href='#'>Session3 FH</a><br/>
                    <a href='#'>Session3 FH</a>
                </div>
            </div>
       };
         else {
         /* 
         final condition code
          */
         }} ?>
    </div>
             </li>
```